# Type that match string with arbitrary number of arguments separated by comma

Tags: typescript

Title is self-explanatory. I'd like a type that can match string starting with the prefix `func` and surrounded by an arbitrary number of arguments between two parenthesis.

```
func(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
func(1, 2, 3)
func(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

Currently I wrote the following type which is not 100% what I want since it can have any string between those parenthesis:

```
type MyType = `func(${string})`
```

Comment: Where are you going to use this type? As a type for a parameter? Return type?

Comment: Actually is to validate an object value. Example:

Comment: And what are the arguments going to be? Are they only going to be numbers? If not, what else?

Comment: value: {
    numberValue: '$sys.func.ADD($session.params.param, 1)',
}

Comment: Yikes... so the arguments can be things other than numbers... Do you have a list of everything it could possibly be? If it's *any* valid JavaScript, then I don't think it's feasible to do...

Comment: Actually it doen't matter that much the arguments between these parenthesis, my main need it is to validate an arbitraty number of arguments by a specific separator.

Comment: Either way, you need a helper function to infer and validate the string. A "static" type where you use `const myVar: MyType = { ... }` won't work for this.

Comment: Validate **how**? What if it's `func([1, 2, 3])` with an array?

Comment: This situation that you mentioned is not gonna happen. It is only either a number or a string separated by comma.

Comment: But your example is clearly using an identifier as an argument, not a string or a number...  You'll need to give us **all** requirements and restrictions, and please do so as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76038674/edit) to the post, not as a comment.

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna try be more clear on my post. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you cannot use TypeScript types to validate object values at runtime (for that you would need a regex or a validation library like zod or joi). You can only validate string literals at compile time.

That having been said, answering your question to have a type that works as you explained:

**If** TypeScript supported recursive template literal types it would be simple:

```
type Param = number;
type Params = '' | `${Params}, $Paraam`
type Func = `func(${Params})`
```

Unfortunately, this gives an error for the `Params` type:

> `Type alias 'Params' circularly references itself.ts(2456)`

So instead we have to list out the types manually, with an upper limit:

```
type N = number;
type Params = ''
  | `${N}`
  | `${N}, ${N}`
  | `${N}, ${N}, ${N}`
  | `${N}, ${N}, ${N}, ${N}`
  | `${N}, ${N}, ${N}, ${N}, ${N}`
  | `${N}, ${N}, ${N}, ${N}, ${N}, ${N}`
  | `${N}, ${N}, ${N}, ${N}, ${N}, ${N}, ${N}`

type Func = `func(${Params})`

const f: Func = 'func(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)'; // OK
const g: Func = 'func 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 '; // Error
```

You could remove the need for manually listing them out with a utility type, but since recursive template literal types are not supported, there would still be an upper limit.

Comment: Technically we can remove the limit if we do something like `const f = funcString(...)` and this doesn't really seem to answer the question given that OP said it should at least include strings or numbers (at least, that's what they said to me in the comments).

Comment: I believe I was not that clear because english is not my native language, but @rsp answer partially work for me, the only downside is that there is this parameter limit.

Comment: But I'd like to thank you both for the patience and all the explanation, it really helped my understand a little bit better about the way validation work on typescript.

Comment: @cokakola I'm glad that I could help, even if only partially solving your problem. Good luck and have fun in learning more about TypeScript!